# Why is the algebraic tensor product of two Hilbert spaces a subspace of their Hilbert tensor product?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, operator-algebras

In the book of [Kadison-Ringrose, vol 1](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-15) the authors have defined the *Hilbert Tensor Product*  of two (complex) Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$ to be a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ together with a *weak Hilbert-Schmidt mapping* $p:\mathcal{H}_1 \times\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ satisfying the universal property: any weak Hilbert-Schmidt mapping $L:\mathcal{H}_1 \times\mathcal{H}_2 \to \mathcal{K}$ must factor through a unique bounded linear operator from $T:\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes\mathcal{H}_2\to \mathcal{K}$, i.e., $L=Tp$. (Existence and uniqueness of $(\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes\mathcal{H}_2, p)$ is the content of Theorem 2.6.4)

After this, in Proposition 2.6.6, they established the relationship between this *Hilbert tensor product*, $\mathcal{H}_1 \otimes\mathcal{H}_2$, and the *algebraic tensor product*, $\mathcal{H}_1 \odot\mathcal{H}_2$. The latter is defined as the tensor product of  $\Bbb{C}$-modules. More precisely they concluded, from Proposition 2.6.6, the following:

> (**Remark 2.6.7**). The first part of Proposition 2.6.6 asserts, in effect, that the only finite families of simple tensors that have sum zero **are those that are "forced" to have zero sum by the bilinearity of the mapping** $p:(x,y)\to x\otimes y$. From this the subspace, $\mathcal{H}_0:=\{\sum_{j=1}^n x_j\otimes y_j:x_j \in \mathcal{H}_1, y_j\in \mathcal{H}_2\}$ of $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$, can be identified with $\mathcal{H}_1\odot\mathcal{H}_2$...

- I cannot understand what did they mean by the first line of this remark. I mean what are those simple tensors which have zero sum by the bilinearity of $p$?
- Also, how does that imply that $\mathcal{H}_0$ can be identified with $\mathcal{H}_1\odot\mathcal{H}_2$?

For the second question I tried to proceed as follows:
First let $i:\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathcal{H}_2\to \mathcal{H}_1\odot\mathcal{H}_2$ be the canonical map $i(a, b):=a\odot b$. Then since $p:\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ is weak H-S map so in particular it is bilinear (see Definition 2.6.3) map between the $\Bbb{C}$-modules $p:\mathcal{H}_1\times\mathcal{H}_2\to\mathcal{H}_0$; by universal property of $\mathcal{H}_1\odot\mathcal{H}_2$ we get a *linear* map $T:\mathcal{H}_1\odot\mathcal{H}_2\to \mathcal{H}_0$ satisfying $p = Ti$, i.e., $x\otimes y = T(x\odot y)$ for $x \in \mathcal{H}_1$ and $y \in \mathcal{H}_2$. Now it is enough to prove the injectivity of $T$ , which follows from Proposition 2.6.6, for $x\otimes y=0$ then there is a $c\in \Bbb{C}$ such that $cx=0;cy=y$ which impies $c=1; x=0$ but then $x\odot y=0$. More generally, if $T(\sum_{j =1}^nx_j\odot  y_j)=0$ i.e., $\sum_{j =1}^nx_j\otimes  y_j=0$ which implies, by Proposition 2.6.6, $ \forall k, \sum_jc_{jk}x_j=0$ and $\forall j, \sum_k c_{jk}y_k=y_j$ from which it is easy to see that $\sum_{j =1}^nx_j\odot  y_j=0$.

Is my argument right? Thanks